# Replace all nulls in a CSV file that is read by C#

Tags: c#, csv, replace, null

I have an input csv file that is read by C#. I want to write a piece of code that scans the file for all 'nulls' and replace with an empty string on the output.

so far I have wrote this. The public FileProcessor() doesnt seem to work

```
class FileProcessor
{      
    //File Objects
    readonly Dictionary<string, FileInfo> _fileDict;

    //DB Objects
    private readonly EMIRDB _emirdb;


    public FileProcessor()
    {
        _fileDict = new Dictionary<string, FileInfo>();
        _emirdb = new EMIRDB();
    }

    public FileProcessor()
    {
        string replacenull = File.ReadAllText ("EMIR_VU_E_");
        replacenull = replacenull.Replace("null", "");
        File.WriteAllText("EMIR_VU_E_", replacenull);
    }
```

Comment: Hallo and welcome to SO. I would suggest you try yourself. If you are new to C# I suggest you first familiarize with the language and then try to solve the problem you are describing. This is not a site where you can ask people to write code for you. You should try yourself, and then come here in case something is not working as expected. Giving a detailed explanation on what you expect and what you are getting and what you have tried.

Comment: Adding to that, the text `null` is a perferctly valid value for a CSV. It's just four letters. Which means you *SHOULDN'T* try to replace it because you'll mangle other data, eg `This is just a null case`. If the file's specification says that the string `null` represents missing data, you should either make the replacement yourself *after* you read the file, or configure your CSV reader (which you didn't mention) to handle it this way

Comment: Which brings us to null bytes in the *file*. There aren't any. Either this is NOT a CSV file, or it's a Unicode file where all ANSI characters start with a NUL byte (ie 0x00). There's nothing wrong with it and `File.ReadAllText` can handle it just fine. *.NET's strings* are Unicode themselves

Comment: @mjwills Yes its wirtten as 'null' in the field. Its a requirement to remove the nulls. The code needs to remove the word 'null' on the input csv files and replace it with an empty string.

Comment: @Iasha where *is* the code that reads a CSV? You haven't posted anything relevant. Are you using a library? Your own code? Why don't you simply check each field's value and replace it? Besides, many CSV libraries allow you to specify a string that is handled as NULL

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0111 Type 'FileProcessor' already defines a member called '.ctor' with the same parameter types EMIRAutoTRSUnavista H:\EMIR ASIC TFS Location\Development\EMIRAutoTRS\FileProcessor.cs 27 Active
@mjwills

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have two constructors with the same set of parameters (in this case, zero parameters).

Thus:

```
public FileProcessor()
{
    _fileDict = new Dictionary<string, FileInfo>();
    _emirdb = new EMIRDB();
}

public FileProcessor()
{
    string replacenull = File.ReadAllText ("EMIR_VU_E_");
    replacenull = replacenull.Replace("null", "");
    File.WriteAllText("EMIR_VU_E_", replacenull);
}
```

is not allowed.

You need to remove one of the constructors. *Or move the code from one constructor into the other.*

Comment: Thanks! I placed it into the first constructor and it worked